# Automatically mark emails as "not spam" based on subject in Outlook

Tags: outlook

We have a ticketing system where all our outgoing emails contains "Ticket (xxxx) - email subject", where xxxx is the ticket number. Some emails from our customers comes back to us marked as spam, and is put in the "junk folder" in outlook.

Is it possible to make a rule or similar in Outlook that all incoming emails containing "Ticket (" should be marked as "not spam" and put in the inbox folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search:
Try to;
Make a rule(Settings>Email>Rules) With a condition 'Subject Includes' "Ticket" and an action for 'Move to' 'Inbox' or 'Mark with importance' or similar

Comment: Yep, but not possible to mark as "not spam/junk". The problem is that when the customers send in the first email, it doesn't have the ticket number in the subject. So we will not notice these emails.

Comment: If this is a purely internal/local system and you feel safe in doing so, you can disable the spam filter all together. In the Outlook app for Windows; Select Home > * * * > 'Move and delete' > 'Junk Email Options'. Check the radio button for "No automatic filtering" and than Apply settings. This will disable the junk filter for all incoming mail.

Comment: Well, we have connected 40 mailboxes to this mailbox, so we are getting thousands of emails every day, so and 99.9% of all emails in the junk mailbox is correctly marked as junk.

So we cannot disable it.